# What does the shader function surf do

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity, a Standard Surface Shader comes with a surf function

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
{
```

When is this function called, and what should it be used to do?
Where can the language reference for the function be found?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/56574/unity-shaders-what-is-surf.html asks the same question but get no definitive answer and no indication of when/how often the function is called.

Comment: I think that is the function that Unity will use to create vertex and fragment code.

From : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html
`surfaceFunction - which Cg function has surface shader code. The function should have the form of void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o), where Input is a structure you have defined. Input should contain any texture coordinates and extra automatic variables needed by surface function.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you quite understand the concept of **Surface Shaders**.

As written [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html):

> Surface Shaders in Unity is a code generation approach that makes it much easier to write lit shaders than using low level vertex/pixel shader programs. Note that there are no custom languages, magic or ninjas involved in Surface Shaders; it just generates all the repetitive code that would have to be written by hand. You still write shader code in HLSL.

How it works

> You define a “surface function” that takes any UVs or data you need as
>   input, and fills in output structure SurfaceOutput. SurfaceOutput
>   basically describes properties of the surface (it’s albedo color,
>   normal, emission, specularity etc.). You write this code in HLSL.
>
> Surface Shader compiler then figures out what inputs are needed, what
>   outputs are filled and so on, and generates actual vertex&pixel
>   shaders, as well as rendering passes to handle forward and deferred
>   rendering.

Comment: I was thinking of surf as a function gets called once every frame for each pixel, which got me nice and confused.

So, "When is this function called" isn't really a valid question, because the surf function is just used to generate the actual code that runs.  It tells Unity how I want the surface as a whole to behave, colour, emission, specular etc..

Is that right?

During gameplay, if I change a material property on my shader, will surf get ran again?

Comment: Right, Surface Shader is just a template. No, Surface Shader only exists until it's compiled, once the shader is compiled, it becomes an actual vertex&pixel shader, so if you were to change a material property, it would change the actual vertex&pixel shader.